# Sort list of Dict By Multiple Keys, Including List

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to sort this list of dicts by a list key and then by date.
I am trying to sort the dicts by 'label' according the label_order and then by descending 'date'.

```
label_order = [3, 4, 2, 1]

data = [
    {'label': 1, 'data': 5, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 3, 'data': 2, 'date': datetime(2017, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 3, 'data': 1, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 4, 'data': 3, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 4, 'data': 4, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 25)},
]
```

After sorting would look like this:

```
data = [
    {'label': 3, 'data': 1, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 3, 'data': 2, 'date': datetime(2017, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 4, 'data': 3, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 4, 'data': 4, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 25)},
    {'label': 1, 'data': 5, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
]
```

I've tried lambda expressions and itemgetter, but I am having difficulty combining the right strategies for the sort key.  Maybe it is just trying to do too much at one time.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `label_order.index(item['label'])` returns the index of each item's label in that list, which corresponds to its sorting order.

Comment: Let's see the lambda that got you closest to your expected result

Comment: I would change `label_order` to a dictionary that maps the label to it's sorting position. I.e. 3 comes first, then 4, so it should be `{3:1, 4:2, 2:3, 1:4}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky to sort dates in reverse order. Instead, let's use the *negative* of the label's index so they're sorted in descending order. Then we can reverse the sorting and get the results in the order we actually want!

```
from datetime import datetime

label_order = [3, 4, 2, 1]

data = [
    {'label': 1, 'data': 5, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 3, 'data': 2, 'date': datetime(2017, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 3, 'data': 1, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 4, 'data': 3, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
    {'label': 4, 'data': 4, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 25)},
]

def descending_sort_key(item):
    return -label_order.index(item['label']), item['date']

data.sort(key=descending_sort_key, reverse=True)
```

Voila - no date math or other trickery.

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient approach is to build a dict that maps items in `label_order` to indices, so that you can use the indices as keys when performing the sort:

```
keys = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(label_order)}
sorted(data, key=lambda d: (-keys[d['label']], d['date']), reverse=True)
```

This returns:

```
[{'label': 3, 'data': 1, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
 {'label': 3, 'data': 2, 'date': datetime(2017, 12, 31)},
 {'label': 4, 'data': 3, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)},
 {'label': 4, 'data': 4, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 25)},
 {'label': 1, 'data': 5, 'date': datetime(2018, 12, 31)}]
```